# Microsoft Interop is not Working Without Installing Microsoft Excel on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Here You can see my code

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

```
        Microsoft.Office. Interop.Excel.Application oexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook obook;
        oexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        obook = oexcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", true,     
        System.Reflection.Missing.Value, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        try
        {
            obook.SaveAs(Path, Password: password, ConflictResolution:                                                                                XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);
        }
        finally
        {
            obook.Close();
            oexcel.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Can you give me solution for below to run  without installing Microsoft Excel on  Server

Comment: Did you do do some research about Excel alternatives?

Comment: Yes I have tried  using Openxml and Spire.xls but i got same issue on server

Comment: Take a look at EPPlus, it works without Excel installed: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Ricardo  I will try with EPPlus and let you know

Comment: Can You Tel me using Microsoft.interop I have Created  Password Protected Excel Its Working Fine on Local but when i will put on Server not working? give some solution.  will work open XML ?

Comment: I never tried to save a file with password, I really don't know if will work.

Comment: Anyone can tel me how i can do above?

Comment: Anyone can tel me how i can solve below  without installing Microsoft Excel on Server with password Protected Excel
I have Created Password Protected Excel Its Working Fine on Local but when i will put on Server not working? give some solution. will work open XML ?